# Where can i find "Pay by Facebook" API?

Tags: api, facebook, payment-gateway

facebook has the facebook credit and I knew that they are testing on pay by facebook.
anyone know where can I find the API for that? I search in the facebook developer wiki and cannot find anything.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't belive you can use those features as of yet ...

The last I've read about this was [here](http://www.allfacebook.com/2009/10/facebook-payments-gifts-library/) ...

> “The payments methods have been
>   available since we started looking at
>   extending our virtual currency —
>   Facebook Credits — via a very small
>   alpha test with a handful of
>   developers in May. The gifts methods
>   have been available since we started a
>   similar alpha test in August that
>   allows third party developers to offer
>   virtual gifts in the Facebook Gift
>   Shop. **Both methods can only being used
>   by developers that are part of these
>   tests**.”

You might want to keep an eye on this site http://www.allfacebook.com/tag/payments/

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Facebook Credits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/)